Optimisation in updating of data in dataFrame in python
Actually i have given a code to optimise such that it will run under 1 min, now running in 5-8 min, i have applied many concepts but unable to optimise the code . So want help in the same.
Problem i discovered is , in loop when we are trying to update dataframes, that will take a lot of time to do do
Code :
i = CAT
ST_DATA_TEMP = ST_DATA
DC_STK_TEMP = DC_STK_DATA.loc[(DC_STK_DATA['REV_DC_STK']>0)].reset_index(drop=True)
cnt=0

gen_clr_to_merchcat = DC_STK_TEMP.set_index('GEN_CLR')['MERCHCAT'].to_dict()
comb_to_artreq = ST_DATA_TEMP.groupby('COMB')['ART_REQ'].first().to_dict()


concatenated_combinations = {str(j) + str(k): (j, k) for j in ST_DETAILS['ST_CD'] for k in DC_STK_TEMP['GEN_CLR']}

art_req_sums = ST_DATA_TEMP.groupby('COMB')['ART_REQ'].sum().to_dict()
rev_dc_stk_sums = DC_STK_TEMP.groupby('GEN_CLR')['REV_DC_STK'].sum().to_dict()
mj_req_sums = MJ_MBQ.groupby('COMB')['MJ_REQ'].sum().to_dict()
mc_req_sums = MC_MBQ.groupby('COMB')['MC_REQ'].sum().to_dict()
for comb, (j, k) in concatenated_combinations.items():
    l = gen_clr_to_merchcat[k]
    ART_REQ = art_req_sums.get(str(j)+str(k), 0)
    cnt+=1
    print(cnt)
    if rev_dc_stk_sums.get(k) >= ART_REQ:
        if comb_to_artreq.get(comb)>0:
            if mj_req_sums.get(str(j)+str(i)) >= ART_REQ:
                if mc_req_sums.get(str(j)+str(l)) >= ART_REQ:
                    ALLOC = ART_REQ
                    # Batch update for ST_DATA_TEMP
                    updates_st = ST_DATA_TEMP['COMB'] == comb
                    ST_DATA_TEMP.loc[updates_st, 'ALLOC'] = ALLOC
                    ST_DATA_TEMP.loc[updates_st, 'ART_REQ'] -= ALLOC

                    # Batch update for DC_STK_TEMP
                    updates_dc = DC_STK_TEMP['GEN_CLR'] == k
                    DC_STK_TEMP.loc[updates_dc, 'ALLOC'] += ALLOC
                    DC_STK_TEMP.loc[updates_dc, 'REV_DC_STK'] -= ALLOC

                    # Batch update for MJ_MBQ
                    updates_mj = MJ_MBQ['COMB'] == str(j) + str(i)
                    MJ_MBQ.loc[updates_mj, 'ALLOC'] += ALLOC
                    MJ_MBQ.loc[updates_mj, 'MJ_REQ'] -= ALLOC

                    # Batch update for MC_MBQ
                    updates_mc = MC_MBQ['COMB'] == str(j) + str(l)
                    MC_MBQ.loc[updates_mc, 'ALLOC'] += ALLOC
                    MC_MBQ.loc[updates_mc, 'MC_REQ'] -= ALLOC

i have tried almost everything , but nothing worked want to run loop under 1 min

Pandas is not intended to be used with for loops. Try using vectorized operations between dataframes or apply() method at least. It will be much faster. Not sure if you will reach you 1 minute goal, but it will be better for sure.

And even better is to avoid apply() and use at least a list comprehension as mentioned in here. You can expect x25 performance boost.

hi @antoine thanks for your help, but may you help me in code, i cannot be able to understand and apply vectorised instead of loop

hi @dmayilyan thanks for your help, but may you help me in code, i cannot be able to understand and apply code at my level having basic knowledge

Based on the request in the comment above, here is a sample usage of a list comprehension:
import pandas as pd

# Create a dictionary with data
data = {
    "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eva"],
    "Age": [25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Define a custom function to be applied to our DataFrame:
def is_above_30(df):
    return pd.Series([i > 30 for i in df["Age"]])

And apply it to the initial column:
df["Age"] = is_above_30(df)

Note: Modify the function to match your needs.
